# MPAndroidChart. How to use data sets with different data types on single chart?

Tags: android, charts, formatting, mpandroidchart, linechart

I am trying to combine multiple line charts in a single view but i cannot solve problem with different data types. I've tried to use min-max normalization to scale values from different data sets but when i want to show selected value in custom marker view, i cannot convert it back to initial format.
I've tried to use different ValueFormatters for all my data sets but i have not achieved anything.

Normalization code:

```
    private List<Entry> normalizeEntry(List<Entry> entries, int min, int max) {
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++) {
            float lastValue = entries.get(i).getY();
            float newValue = normalize(lastValue, min, max, 0, 100);
            entries.set(i, new Entry(i, newValue));
        }
        return entries;
    }
```

Picture which show what i want to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by adding a parameter corresponding to the value before normalization to the constructor of the Entry object.

```
before:
new Entry(xValue, normalizedValue);
after:
new Entry(xValue, normalizedValue, initialValueWithOutputFormat);
```

Example:

```
 entries.add(new Entry(i, normalizedValues.get(i), String.format("%.2f m", inputValues.get(i))));
```

Then, I can easily update custom marker like in following code:

```
public class CustomMarkerView extends MarkerView {

    private TextView tvContent;

    public CustomMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
        super(context, layoutResource);
        // this markerview only displays a textview
        tvContent = findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    }

    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {
        tvContent.setText(String.valueOf(e.getData()));
        super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
    }

    @Override
    public MPPointF getOffset() {
        return new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2), -getHeight());
    }

}
```